# RBS installed completely but doesn't store files

Tags: rbs

i installed and configured RBS following [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748631.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and did it with no error, but if i upload a big file it doesn't go to Blobstore folder or it's RBSID in database ( DocStreams) is null, means that it stored in content database, i have no idea where to start troubleshooting, so any advice will be helpful.

PS: in following that article i have two dark point, that might cause the problem .

1: **install the RBS client library on all additional web and application servers**; i have two server, one for SQL and SharePoint (which i install RBS on that) and one for Domain controller, so is it needed to install RBS on DC?

2: i don't now much about permissions and did all of configuration with SP system account. where can i check if the problem could be from permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem! files that i upload was "Shredded" and never become bigger than 1 MB to go to RBS, so I change MinimumBolbStoreageSize with this code in SharePoint Management Shell and it works:

```
$cdb = Get-SPContentDatabase “WSS_Content"
$rbss = $cdb.RemoteBlobStorageSettings 
$rbss.MinimumBlobStorageSize = 1000 
$cdb.update()
```

i strongly recommend to read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/briangre/archive/2015/02/19/sharepoint-2013-shredded-storage-vs-rbs.aspx) article if you don't know how RBS and Shred feature in SharePoint work together just like me :)